# Export canvas with jspdf returns black map PDF

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, export, pdf

I built a basic webmap interface with some vector layers and basemaps (eg. openstreetmap) in OpenLayers. When I try to export the canvas with jspdf, the corresponding pdf-file shows a completely black map. How can I export the actual canvas? I don't have a lot of experience in JS yet and have been searching for quite some time, but can't find the mistake in this code.

```
var dims = {
    a0: [1189, 841],
    a1: [841, 594],
    a2: [594, 420],
    a3: [420, 297],
    a4: [297, 210],
    a5: [210, 148],
};

var exportButton = document.getElementById('export-pdf');

exportButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    exportButton.disabled = true;
    document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

    var format = 'a4'
    var resolution = '300'
    var dim = dims[format];
    var width = Math.round((dim[0] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var height = Math.round((dim[1] * resolution) / 25.4);
    var size = map.getSize();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();

    map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
      var mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      mapCanvas.width = width;
      mapCanvas.height = height;
      var mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
        function (canvas) {
          if (canvas.width > 0) {
            var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
            mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
            var transform = canvas.style.transform;
            // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
            var matrix = transform
              .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
              .split(',')
              .map(Number);
            // Apply the transform to the export map context
            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
              mapContext,
              matrix
            );
            mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
          }
        }
      );
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(
        mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
        'JPEG',
        0,
        0,
        dim[0],
        dim[1]
      );
      pdf.save('map.pdf');
      // Reset original map size
      map.setSize(size);
      map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
      exportButton.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    // Set print size
    var printSize = [width, height];
    map.setSize(printSize);
    var scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);
    map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution / scaling);
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: Since it's exact copy of OpenLayers print to PDF example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html, it should work. Any errors in browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: It is probably due to something in your layer setup. Do all your tile or WMS sources specify a crossOrigin option where not already defaulted? (needed to avoid tainted canvas, the OSM layer in the example defaults to 'anonymous'). Do the layers specify a className? (the example code is only looking for the default 'ol-layer'). Changes will also be needed to export a heatmap layer https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11014

Comment: @ TomazicM: No errors in the console.
@ Mike:  There's no crossOrigin attribute defined for any of the tile and WMS sources, but OSM for example should have that by default no? Layers do not have a className.

Comment: Then you have to resort to classic debugging: first map with only OSM layer. If this does not work, further isolation is necessary. If it works, add layer by layer and see where it fails.